# Use composition, strategy pattern and dictionary to better instantiate class stored in dictionary

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, pygame, roguelike

I develop a RogueLike in python, and I try to make my best with OOP and my little knowledge to construct a python course for student.

```
mapRogue = ['~~~~~~~~~~',
            '~~~~.....Y',
            'YYYYY+YYYY',
            'YYYY....YY']
```

I want to transform this string map into 2D list containing object defining the nature of my tile in the RogueLike. For that I decide to use a dictionary to map character key and class to instantiate when I read this variable `mapRogue`.

I find a solution using inheritance, but imho this code is not really as elegant as i want, and probably not very flexible if I want to add other type of tile behavior later.

## DOOR class using inheritance

```
class Tile(object):
    #a tile of the map and its properties
    def __init__(self, name, char, position, blocked, color=(255, 255, 255), bgcolor=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.name = name
        self.blocked = blocked
        self.char = char
        self.color = color
        self.bgcolor = bgcolor
        self.position = position

class Door(Tile):
    def __init__(self,  name, char, position, blocked, bgcolor, key,color=(255, 255, 255), open=False ):
        Tile.__init__( self,name, char, position, blocked, color, bgcolor)
        self.state = open
        self.key = key

    def opening(self, key):
        if self.key == key:
            self.state = True

tilesObject = {".": {"name": 'floor', "obj": Tile, "bgcolor": (233, 207, 177), "block": False},
               "Y": {"name": 'forest', "obj": Tile, "bgcolor": (25, 150, 64), "block": True},
               "~": {"name": 'water', "obj": Tile, "bgcolor": (10, 21, 35), "block": False},
               "+": {"name": 'doors', "obj": Door, "bgcolor": (10, 10, 25), "block": False}}
import types
def load(mymap):
    tileMap = []
    x, y = (0,0)
    for line in mymap:
        tileLine = []
        for value in line:
            try:
                tile = tilesObject[value]
            except KeyError:
                return "Error on key"
            if tile["obj"].__name__ ==  "Door":
                obj = tile["obj"](name=tile["name"], position=(x, y), char=value, blocked=tile["block"],bgcolor=tile["bgcolor"], key="42isTheKey", open=False)
            else:
                obj = tile["obj"](name=tile["name"], position=(x, y), char=value, blocked=tile["block"],bgcolor=tile["bgcolor"])

            x += 1
            tileLine.append(obj)
        x = 0
        y += 1
        tileMap.append(tileLine)
    return tileMap


for line in load(mapRogue):
    for obj in line:
        print obj , "\n"
```

## DOOR class using composition

I suspect there is an other answer using composition and/or strategy pattern, so i try to decorate the Tile object with Door behavior, but i'm blocked with this dictionnary ...

Actually i try multiple solution without success, do you have a proposition to help me to solve this problem of conception using elegant oop and python ?

```
class Tile(object):
    #a tile of the map and its properties
    def __init__(self, name, char, position, blocked, color=(255, 255, 255), bgcolor=(0, 0, 0), door=None):
        self.name = name
        self.blocked = blocked
        self.char = char
        self.color = color
        self.bgcolor = bgcolor
        self.door = door
        self.position = position

# Door decorate the Tile object using composition
class Door(object):
    def __init__(self, key, open=False):
        self.state = open
        self.key = key

    def opening(self, key):
        if self.key == key:
            self.state = True

tilesObject = {".": {"name": 'floor', "obj": Tile, "bgcolor": (233, 207, 177), "block": False},
               "Y": {"name": 'forest', "obj": Tile, "bgcolor": (25, 150, 64), "block": True},
               "~": {"name": 'water', "obj": Tile, "bgcolor": (10, 21, 35), "block": False},
               "+": {"name": 'doors', "obj": Door, "bgcolor": (10, 10, 25), "block": False}}

def load(mymap):
    tileMap = []
    x, y = (0,0)
    for line in mymap:
        tileLine = []
        for value in line:
            try:
                tile = tilesObject[value]
            except KeyError:
                return "Error on key"

            # Here i need to detect when obj is Door 
                    # because i need to define a special Tile 
                    # decorated by Door behavior, 
                    # so it seems this is not a good solution :/

            x += 1
            tileLine.append(obj)
        x = 0
        y += 1
        tileMap.append(tileLine)
    return tileMap
```

## An update with some informations:

Thanks for answer @User and @Hyperborreus, you're right, I simplify my example here, and in my code, I have two layers:

- the `Tile` which don't move,
- and the `GameObjects` which can move, attack, defend, and a lot of other function decorated using `composition` like in this tutorial [here](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2blibtcod,_part_6)

Using `pygame`, I display all my `Tiles` object using a `draw_tile()` function.

So at this point I need a link between `Door` and `Tile` class to compute correctly a fov for player later, because `Door` have behavior and limit the vision of my character (with an attributes blocked or fovState). After that, I drawn all `gameObject`, on top of these already drawed `Tile` surfaces. Door is part of computation only specific to Tile, and other things in roguelike so that explain why I define the `Door` like that I hope.

So probably you're right with your proposition of game definition dictionary, I need to change the way i instantiate object, the oop definition of Door / Tiles rest the same, but when I read the initial string map which contain item, door and also static object, I separate `gameObject` instantiation and `Tile` instantiation..

The idea of dictionary to instantiate element on a rogueLike map defined in string list is based on the idea founded here: https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/dropout/

Perhaps the creator of this code, @dominic-kexel can also help us to on this point?

Comment: Why does the inheritance approach irk you?

Comment: The if test is not really good, and if i have 10 type of tile, i have ten if to test the name of class, it's not very flexible, so if there is another solution more elegant to make the same thing, that's great ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should make a distinction between "tiles" (the underlying basemap) and "objects" (things the player can interact with, like doors that open, dragons that attack, or pits that kill).

If you want to compare this with a 3D-video game, the "tiles" would be the environment you cannot interact with, and the "objects" would be the clickable things.

The mere tiles can be instances of one single class and hold the information relevant and common to all tiles, like rendering hints (which character in which colour) or movement aspects (can be passed, movement speed, etc).

The objects are then placed on top of the tiles.

Imagine you have a map with a lot of floor and walls, and at two positions you have two doors. All "tiles" behave the same (you can walk on floor, no matter which floor tile) but you will butt your head against a wall (no matter where the wall is). But the doors are different: One door requires the "Green Key" and the other door requires the "Embroidered Key of the Dissident Pixie".

This difference is where your `if`-issue arises. The door needs extra information. In order to define a map, you need all tiles (identical within each class) and another lists of objects placed on certain tiles (each object different).

Doors, Wells, Dragons, Switches etc could inherit from a common base class which implements standard actions like "inspect", "interact", "attack", "yell at", and maybe special interfaces for special actions.

So a complete game definition could look like this:

```
game = {'baseMap': '#here comes your 2D array of tiles',
'objects': [ {'class': Door, 'position': (x, y), 'other Door arguments': ...}, 
{'class': Door, 'position': (x2, y2), 'other Door arguments': ...},
{'class': Dragon, 'position': (x3, y3), 'dragon arguments': ...}, ] }
```

Then for instantiating the actual objects (object in the OO sense, not in the game sense), walk throught this definition, and call the c'tor of each object with the dictionary items as keyword-arguments (double-asterisk). This is only one possible approach of many.

For rendering, display the tile presentation if the tile is empty, or the object representation if there is an object on the tile.

---

This is what I mean with double-asterisk:

```
class Door:
    def __init__ (self, position, colour, creaking = True):
        print (position, colour, creaking)

objDefs = [...,
          {'class': Door, 'kwargs': {'position': (2, 3), 'colour': 'black'} },
          ...]

#Here you actually iterate over objDefs
objDef = objDefs [1]
obj = objDef ['class'] (**objDef ['kwargs'] )
```

---

**Big Edit:**

This is an idea of how one could implement the rendering of the map with both tiles and objects. (Just my two cents):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

colours = {'white': 7, 'green': 2, 'blue': 4, 'black': 0, 'yellow': 3}

class Tile:
    data = {'.': ('Floor', 'white', True),
        'Y': ('Forest', 'green', False),
        '~': ('Water', 'blue', False) }

    def __init__ (self, code, position):
        self.code = code
        self.position = position
        self.name, self.colour, self.passable = Tile.data [code]

    def __str__ (self):
        return '\x1b[{}m{}'.format (30 + colours [self.colour], self.code)

class GameObject:
    #here got he general interfaces common to all game objects
    def __str__ (self):
        return '\x1b[{}m{}'.format (30 + colours [self.colour], self.code)

class Door (GameObject):
    def __init__ (self, code, position, colour, key):
        self.code = code
        self.position = position
        self.colour = colour
        self.key = key

    def close (self): pass
        #door specific interface

class Dragon (GameObject):
    def __init__ (self, code, position, colour, stats):
        self.code = code
        self.position = position
        self.colour = colour
        self.stats = stats

    def bugger (self): pass
        #dragon specific interface

class Map:
    def __init__ (self, codeMap, objects):
        self.tiles = [ [Tile (c, (x, y) ) for x, c in enumerate (line) ] for y, line in enumerate (codeMap) ]
        self.objects = {obj ['args'] ['position']: obj ['cls'] (**obj ['args'] ) for obj in objects}

    def __str__ (self):
        return '\n'.join (
            ''.join (str (self.objects [ (x, y) ] if (x, y) in self.objects else tile)
                for x, tile in enumerate (line) )
            for y, line in enumerate (self.tiles)
            ) + '\n\x1b[0m'

mapRouge = ['~~~~~~~~~~',
            '~~~~.....Y',
            'YYYYY.YYYY',
            'YYYY....YY']

objects = [ {'cls': Door,
        'args': {'code': '.', 'position': (5, 2), 'colour': 'black',
        'key': 'Ancient Key of Constipation'} },
    {'cls': Dragon,
        'args': {'code': '@',  'position': (7, 3), 'colour': 'yellow',
        'stats': {'ATK': 20, 'DEF': 20} } } ]

theMap = Map (mapRouge, objects)
print (theMap)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, you're right, i simplify my example here, but in my code, i have two layer, the `Tile` which don't move, and the `GameObjects` which can move, attack, defend, and a lot of other function decorated using `composition` like here http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod,_part_6 etc. So probably you're right with your proposition of game definition, perhaps i need to move the `Door` into the `GameObjects` list. Can you provide an example or a link to this double asterisk instatiation, i'm interested ?

Comment: I edited my answer and included an example of what I mean by kwargs and double-asterisk.

Comment: Thanks again, with this technics is it possible to pass argument during iteration you think ? If i want to specify the (x,y) of object based on my loop over 2DList of string for example ?

Comment: Either pass the position tuple into the kwarg dictionary and pass this dictionary, or pass it as a first positional argument, before the kwargs. Both ways are viable.

Comment: Thanks @Hyperboreus for your help, perhaps other people add other answer later, but i validate your great answer now

Comment: @reyman64 Please see my last edit. This is one of many possible way of implement the map. Maybe you can grab one idea or two from it. (Please run it on a console that understands ANSI escapes, so you can see the colours).

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution to your problem:

```
kw = tile.copy()
cls = kw.pop('obj')
obj = cls(**kw)
```

does the same as

```
        if tile["obj"].__name__ ==  "Door":
            obj = tile["obj"](name=tile["name"], position=(x, y), char=value, blocked=tile["block"],bgcolor=tile["bgcolor"], key="42isTheKey", open=False)
        else:
            obj = tile["obj"](name=tile["name"], position=(x, y), char=value, blocked=tile["block"],bgcolor=tile["bgcolor"])
```

And this is because I value what you do:

I would agree with Hyperboreus that you make a difference between the position = the tile and what is placed on top if the tile.

What worked really well in another game is that tiles are connected:

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left_tile = None
        self.right_tile = None
        ...
        self.content = [FreeSpaceToWalk()]

    def can_I_walk_there(self, person):
        for content in self.content:
            if not content.can_I_walk_there(person): return False
        return True
```

This way you can make portals by connecting tiles that are not neighbors by position.

Here are some contents:

```
class Door:
    password = '42'
    def can_I_walk_there(self, person):
        return person.what_is_the_password_for(self) == self.password

class FreeSpaceToWalk:
    def can_I_walk_there(self, person):
        return True

class Wall:
    def can_I_walk_there(self, person):
        return False
```